# how can input hourly rate and gross income in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Write a program in class to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using input to compute gross pay. Pay the hourly rate for the hours up to 40 and 1.5 times the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75). You should use input to read a string and float() to convert the string to a number

Comment: What did you try so far? What were your results? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We are not going to do your homework. Show us what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

As asked in the Question For input use:

```
hrs = input()
rph = input()
hrs = float(hrs)
rph = float(rph)
```

By the way a shorter way:

```
hrs = float(input())
rph = float(input())
```

Comment: Its as per python 3.x

Comment: For python 2.x replace input() with raw_input()